# Does anyone else experience a lag while typing

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I am experiencing a very long lag while typing at my normal speed, also the site responds very slowly to things like mouse over and clicks. I am on FF 3.5 and puppy linux (it used to work with the same config with the design on chiphacker)

Answer (score 1):

I used to experience this all the time with the original StackOverflow.  Now I experience it with everything!  Spinning the mouse wheel doesn't scroll the page until when it feels like scrolling.   Slow key-to-visible text action, including the backspace.   Just sliding the cursor from one window to another = no action until 10-20 sec later (I use "focus follows mouse" on icewm on a Linux machine)

Other people experience this, but many more with the same setup, same software versions, do not.   It's a known problem, but only among us insiders - like with UFO witnesses, outsiders just don't "believe"!  I've tried obtaining stack dumps using oprofile, gdb, etc but it's not clear what's going on.

It seems to be something to do with the combination of Firefox, running Flash, and the pre... (come on keyboard... soon... come on....ah! what was I saying? oh yeah) presence of certain javascript scripts.  Running a lot of Flash, e.g. an all evening long youtube watching session, will certainly trigger it.  Maybe it's not Flash but some javascript commonly used with Flash on most sites.   Who knows.   (ack! I just experienced a delay of about 30sec, wiggling the mouse.. suddenly this page scrolled up/down/up/down very rapidly)

Solution: 1) use Opera or something else, not FF  2) quit FF, restart.  This doesn't always do it, but quitting my X11 session and restarting always works.   A true solution lies in fixing whatever bad interaction is going on with FF, X, the kernel, and threading.

Comment: Umm.. another believer. I thought I was the only one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and it was one of the firefox plugins that was periodically taking over the process to poll some site looking for updates.

I knew it wasn't the computer (8 core, 8 gig) or network (T3 here at work).

I deleted almost all my plugins and now everything is back to being snappy.  I'm not sure which one was the culprit.

Comment: Can you put up a list of which plugins you were using?

Comment: I wish I could, but there's no record that I can find of which plugins I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

We can't duplicate this -- have you tried running Firefox in "safe mode" (that is, disabling all plugins)?

Comment: have tried everything, cleared my cache, started in safe mode, even my laptop with windows seven and ff has same problem

Comment: @rick we have no other reports of this; not sure what else to check if you have tried a different browser, then I'd say there might be something wrong with your computer.

Comment: Assuming Rick_2047 and I really have the same problem, I can confirm that FF safe mode doesn't matter.  When the problem acts up, other apps can be affected.  And it happens on Ubuntu and Arch Linux.  Along with Puppy, these are the linux distros that attract UFOs the most! :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just seeing the bug that makes my life miserable every day, [bug 646941](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646941).

Restarting Firefox usually helps, but it comes back eventually.

See also [bug 490122](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490122), which describes the general symptom.

(if that *is* what you're seeing then it obviously has nothing to do with StackExchange; it's a Firefox problem)